# ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree rxjs@undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, macos, terminal

I installed Node.js and Angular on my Mac but when I tried to create a project I recieved this error message in the terminal [Terminal output] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i4qc.png)

The version of node.js is 18.14.2 and the version of Angular client is 15.2.0

Is there someone who have encountered a similar problem?

I tried changing the dependencies for the rxjs in the package.json file but it did not give any results.

Edit: this is my package.json file [package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN5BL.png)

Comment: try to delete the node_modules folder and the package-lock file and make the npm install again

Comment: Tried that, but it does not seem to work

Comment: can you share your `package.json` ?

Comment: Updated my post with a screenshot of the package.json file :)